# Oracle what is command for taking backup and restore

Tags: mysql, oracle

In Mysql we are using following commands to take backup and restore.

For Backup

```
Mysqldump -u username -p password Database name > filename.sql;
```

For single table backup

```
Mysqldump -u username -p password Database name table name > filename.sql;
```

For restore

```
Mysql -u username -p password Database name < filename.sql;
```

similarly, I want to know the commands which is using in oracle for the above mentioned actions.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at EXPDP command (or EXP on older versions)

Comment: Use `RMAN user/password` then (assuming you are in `ARCHIVELOG` mode) at the prompt type `BACKUP DATABASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown the database. o/s copy **all** the files (data, control, redo, undo). Restart the database.

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
sqlplus> shutdown immediate
sqlplus> exit
$ cp /your/oracle/data-paths/* /your/oracle/backup-path/
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
sqlplus> startup
sqlplus> exit
$
```